# Get a live notification when a customer is on a certain page

Tags: google-analytics, zapier, livechat

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for a while and surprised it doesn't exist. I have a low traffic site but a high conversion/acquisition cost per customer.

So when a customer hits a certain page on my website, I want to be notified via SMS. So I can instigate a live chat and get them converting.

I have tried an option with Google Analytics, but that seems to have a delay. The live chat platforms do not seem to have this feature.

How could this type of action be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That certainly might be possible! I haven't tried anything like that, but I have an idea that might work (albeit with some caveats).

First, you'll want to trigger when someone is on the site. For that, I'd send a webbhook to Zapier from the front-end of the page. If you wanted to only trigger if someone is there for a few seconds (not a bounce) you can put the outgoing webhook in a `setTimeout`. If you have the following code:

```
fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/my/hook/path')
```

It will contact Zapier. From there, you can use SMS by Zapier to text yourself. You could also pass along relevant data to be used in the text, if you wanted.

All that said, it seems like live-chat apps (something like [Olark](https://www.olark.com/)) will make it seem like you're online always and can forward incoming messages to you somewhere you can respond right away. I haven't tried any, but I can't imagine yours is a unique problem.

Comment: Interesting, so just drop the fetch code into some javascript on said page or perhaps within the html body code. Just dreaming but would be great if you could match it to referer (google/cpc) as well. As I say, surprised it is not out there as a product. BTW, Love Zapier! Could it not be a push notification, or does that only works with apps?

Comment: A push notification has to go through an app, yes. You can use an app like [pushover](https://zapier.com/apps/pushover/integrations) or [pushbullet](https://zapier.com/apps/pushbullet/integrations) as the action instead.